# Set Jframe not to be on top always

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have designed a `JFrame` and set it to full screen mode using `GraphicsDevice`, the problem is that `JFrame` is now always on top and I can't see the other window, even when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. How do I correctly get the `JFrame` to not always be on top when using `GraphicsDevice`?

```
public class MyResolution {

        public MyResolution() {
            GraphicsEnvironment env=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice device=env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            GraphicsConfiguration gc=device.getDefaultConfiguration();
            JFrame frame=new JFrame();
            DisplayMode mode=new DisplayMode(1024, 768, 16,0);
            device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
            frame.setSize(300,500);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            DisplayMode[] modes = device.getDisplayModes();
            for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println("Best display mode: "+mode+", Modes:-"+modes[i]);
                if (modes[i].getWidth() == mode.getWidth()
                        && modes[i].getHeight() == mode.getHeight()
                        && modes[i].getBitDepth() == mode.getBitDepth()) {
                    device.setDisplayMode(mode);            }
            }
            frame.enableInputMethods(false);    
            frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                MyResolution mine=new MyResolution();       
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use next for your `JFrame` [`frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29).

`frame` is your `JFrame`.

Comment: thanks but i tried this method and is not working as i have used GrapgicsDevice

Comment: Edit your question with that.

Comment: toFront, alwayson.... are methods that woking for JDialog, bunch of idiotic mistakes based on declared properties for Windows OS, miracles that doesn't works for JFrame, historical issue (Win2000/NT ????)

Comment: GraphicsEnvironment env=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
  GraphicsDevice device=env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
  GraphicsConfiguration gc=device.getDefaultConfiguration();
  JFrame frame=new JFrame(gc);
  DisplayMode mode=new DisplayMode(1024, 768, 16,0);
  device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);frame.setSize(300,500);
    DisplayMode[] modes = device.getDisplayModes();